# Padding on the parent does not affect child width

Tags: html, css

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vajrzfn0/11/)

I have a container, I want to place subjects on that. Problem is string `maths` is not taking 100% width of its parent.

I suspect it is because of padding on the parent. I want to achieve the same design but `Maths` string should be centered and takes full width[including padding] of parent

```
  .clsSubjectCircle {
border: 1px solid;
border-radius: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 30px;
position: relative;
top: 22%;
max-width: 22%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

And tell me what are all the bad practices in my design.

[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/vajrzfn0/13/) explains the problem. I can understand that padding causes the problem

Changing `max-width` to `width` and adding `height` solves the problem, But it affects centering feature of child divs

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you expect the font size to adjust based on its container's width? That's quite unusual and not trivial, but can be done using the `vw` unit.

Comment: No, I want the `maths` div width to be 100% of its parent in this case parent is `circle's parent`

Comment: I still don't understand. Can you provide a simpler example with as little code as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use additional wrapper to take 100% width of the parent. i.e. I've added `<div class='customPadding'>` and position your `.subName` with positioning absolute.

```
       <div class="subName">Maths</div>
       <div class='customPadding'>
           <div class="completion">0%</div>
       </div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vajrzfn0/17/)

Set Circle's width and height property in terms of Pixel, not percentage.

**Reason :** Circle roundness completely depends on the container DIV, if the width and height of the parent is varied, your circle may looks like **ellipse**. Atleast assign both width and height property to same percentage.

Your `maths` div was working correctly, because it takes 100% from the inside-box (i.e. excluding padding, margin and border). If you want it to take complete space, place it outside the container and position it absolutely as suggested above/fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.clsUserSubjects {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.clsUserSubject {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 200px;
}
/*
.subName {
    align-self: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}*/

.clsSubjectCircle {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  height: 138px;
  width: 138px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.completion {
  text-align: center;
}
.subName {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="clsUserSubjects">
  <div id="maths" class="clsUserSubject">
    <div class="clsSubjectCircle">
      <div class="subName">Maths</div>
      <div class="completion">0%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```